# Keeping an echo'd checkbox checked after page is refreshed

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

I am new to web design and an intern doing some web maintenance and changes to my company's website. Long story short we lost our newest backup of the website and lost some functionality of our website and this was some of it.

```
foreach ($regions as $region) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td><input class=\"live-region\" id=\"".$region['ID']."\" type=\"checkbox\" value></td>";
    echo "<td><label id=\"".$region['ID']."\" for=\"".$region['ID']."\">".$region['name']."</label></td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
```

I just need the echo'd "regions" with their associated check boxes to stay checked if the page is refreshed. I've tried some javascripts but they check all the boxes even if only one was checked. Thanks for any help!!

Comment: Sessions? Cookies? What JS have you tried?

Comment: Put a css class e.g. "checked_option"

Comment: The Javascript I used LocalStorage to keep the box checked, it worked but also checked all the boxes on the page even if only one box was checked.

Comment: I could use a css class with a "checked_option" but wouldnt that just be hardcoding the box to be checked? this still needs to be a dynamic checkbox, I just need it to save its "checked" data.

Answer (score 0):

You could use jQuery.

```
$("input[type=checkbox]").change(function() { $(this).toggleClass("checkedBox"); });
```

Then running through the elements with the class and set checked to true/false.